# implement On click listener in RecyclerView Scroll listener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm using Recycleview to show contacts images and name in Horizontal RecyclerView and it load fine. I have implemented Click listener which on click opens new activity and show details os user based on position of RecyclerView.

But I want autoscroll for RecyclerView such that on every 5 sec, recycleview automatically scrolls and I implemented below code and it works fine.

```html
 top.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int lastItem = llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if(lastItem == llm.getItemCount()-1){
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE);
                    Handler postHandler = new Handler();
                    postHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            top.setAdapter(null);
                            top.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 5000);
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });
        mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 5000);
```

But now when I click on any contact then nothing happens as before where new activity launches with user details. But when I remove scroll listener then again I can click on RecyclerView items.

My RecyclerView is

```html
      final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        top.setLayoutManager(llm);
        top.setHasFixedSize(true);
        staggeredBooksAdapter = new TopAdapter(this, bookslist);

        top.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);
```

and from adapter class is

```html
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        g = bookslist.get(position);

        holder.teacher_location.setText(g.getBlocas());
        holder.teacher_name.setText(g.getSellername());

        holder.profile_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                g = bookslist.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), gender_details.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_IMAGE, g.getPics());



                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

How can I solve this..Thanks in advance.

Comment: implement `onScrollStateChanged` with addOnScrollListener and log the state. see if the state is idled or scrolling when you are clicking on recyclerView item

Comment: can you show me some example of what you  suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Add [this](https://github.com/symphonyrecords/Data/blob/master/RecyclerItemClickListener.java) class to your project and then add below code:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
        this, top, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Log.i("recyclerView ", "onItemClick " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Log.i("recyclerView ", "onLongItemClick " + position);
    }
}));
```

Let me know if it works.